# System.InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, scriptmanager

In the following code file I have written ajax modal popup code on line no. 47 And I am getting error saying only one instance of scriptManager can be added to the page i am yet learning asp.net Please help me solve the error.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Bags.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bags" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style>
.modalBackground {
        background-color: black;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 90) !important;
        opacity: 0.6 !important;
        z-index: 20;
    }

    .modalpopup {
        padding: 20px 0px 24px 10px;
        position: relative;
        width: 450px;
        height: 66px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form id="RegistrationsForm" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" ID="GridViewEntry" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewEntry_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FULL NAME" DataField="full_name"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bag ID" DataField="LID"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tag ID" DataField="RFID"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="state"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="At" DataField="At"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="LostButton" runat="server"
                            CommandName="Lost"
                            CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                            Text="Lost" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" />



                        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>




                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup">
                            Desription : 
                            <br></br>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Desription" runat="server" placeholder="Optional"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br></br>
                            <asp:Button ID="OK" runat="server" Text="OK" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" CancelControlID="Cancel" OkControlID="OK" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="LostButton" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                        <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                            <asp:Label ID="LblError" runat="server">No Information Found! Please Check Again Later!</asp:Label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</div>
```

Bags.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Bags : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 private  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BAGTRACKConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
private  int fid = 1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] == null))
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ref_id"] != null)
        {
            fid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ref_id"]);
            GVBind();

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
        }
    }
}

protected void GVBind()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CONCAT(P.fname,' ',P.lname) AS full_name , L.LID ,L.RFID ,S.state ,B.At_time as At from  Flight F , Ticket T , Passenger P ,Luggage L , BagTrip B ,Status S where T.FID = F.FID and T.username = P.username and  L.TID = T.TID and B.ReaderID = S.ReaderID and B.LID = L.LID and F.FID = @FID ", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FID", fid);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    GridViewEntry.DataSource = ds;
    GridViewEntry.DataBind();
}



protected void GridViewEntry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = GridViewEntry.SelectedRow;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into LostRepository values(@LID,0,@desription,@time)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LID", row.Cells[1]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desription", (GridViewEntry.SelectedRow.FindControl("Desription") as TextBox).Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FID", fid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because you have multiple `ToolkitScriptManager` in your page. You have placed `ToolkitScriptManager` in your `GridView` control that's why it's render multiple times. Please remove `ToolkitScriptManager` from `GridView` and place it below `form` tag.

Check this code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Bags.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bags" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .modalBackground {
            background-color: black;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 90) !important;
            opacity: 0.6 !important;
            z-index: 20;
        }

        .modalpopup {
            padding: 20px 0px 24px 10px;
            position: relative;
            width: 450px;
            height: 66px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form id="RegistrationsForm" runat="server">

            <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

            <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" ID="GridViewEntry" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewEntry_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FULL NAME" DataField="full_name"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bag ID" DataField="LID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tag ID" DataField="RFID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="state"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="At" DataField="At"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="LostButton" runat="server"
                                CommandName="Lost"
                                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                                Text="Lost" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-success" />

                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup">
                                Desription : 
                            <br></br>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Desription" runat="server" placeholder="Optional"></asp:TextBox>
                                <br></br>
                                <asp:Button ID="OK" runat="server" Text="OK" />
                                <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                            </asp:Panel>

                            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" CancelControlID="Cancel" OkControlID="OK" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="LostButton" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>


                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-12'>
                            <div class='alert alert-warning'>
                                <asp:Label ID="LblError" runat="server">No Information Found! Please Check Again Later!</asp:Label>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

            </asp:GridView>
        </form>
    </div>
```